# SQL to linq Having Clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to write the following SQL query in C# using LINQ, what is the best approach to get the same outcome?

```
SELECT [t1].[JOB]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[JOB], [t0].[LINK], [t0].[PREFIX]
    FROM [dbo].[LABELS] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[JOB], [t0].[LINK], [t0].[PREFIX]
    HAVING [t0].[PREFIX] = 'B' AND [t0].[LINK] != 0
    ) AS [t1]
GROUP BY [t1].[JOB], [t1].[value]
HAVING [t1].[value] > 1
```

Labels should be unique on fields JOB and LINK, the combination should never repeat. This query is check which JOBs are breaking that rule

Edit: My LINQ so far as requested, it does not produce the expected result.

```
dbP.PackagingLabels.GroupBy(l => new {l.JOB, l.LINK, l.PREFIX})
    .Where(g => g.Select(e => e.PREFIX != "B" && e.LINK != 0).Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key.JOB);
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so far to solve this problem, and what problems are you having with your solution?

Comment: Although it's good that you provided us with the SQL for reference, we also need to know what you have in LINQ so far as well, to see where exactly you're getting stuck.

Comment: Everything in the inner `HAVING` clause belongs in a where clause instead.

Comment: Actually the outer HAVING should be a where isntead, but of course the WHERE needs to be before the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could simplify this greatly:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [counts], [t0].[JOB], [t0].[LINK]
FROM [dbo].[LABELS] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[PREFIX] = 'B' AND [t0].[LINK] != 0
GROUP BY [t0].[JOB], [t0].[LINK]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Again just like your SQL query, your LINQ should apply the WHERE clause first:

```
var groupsOfDupes = dbP.PackagingLabels
   .Where(e => e.PREFIX != "B" && e.LINK != 0)
   .GroupBy(l => new {l.JOB, l.LINK})
   .Where(grp => grp.Skip(1).Any()) //this returns true if there is more than one item in the group
   .ToList();
```

This will give you a list of groups.  Note each item in the list is itself a list.  The inner list being the items which share the same JOB and LINK.

```
foreach(var group in groupsOfDupes)
{
   Console.WriteLine( "This combination has count > 1: { JOB: '" + group.Key.JOB  + "', LINK: '" + group.Key.LINK + "' } with count of: " + group.Count());
}
```

Comment: This may be the case, but it still doesn't completely answer the question as asked.

Comment: The goal is to get a list of the jobs. This was my original query though.

Comment: "Labels should be unique on fields JOB and LINK" from your question, see prior edit revision for jobs only

Comment: a row is unique on jobs and link. meaning a row with job 1 link 1 will only exist once, job 1 link 2 will only exist once job 2 link 1 will only exist once. etc. another job 1 link 1 breaks the rules. Keep in mind, this isn't a constraint on the table, that is the point of the query, I'm trying to find who's breaking the rule.

Comment: That's what this does, that's what I quoted your requirement as, and that's what this code does `.GroupBy(l => new {l.JOB, l.LINK})`.  Each IGrouping represents a unique JOB LINK combination.

Comment: @Oxymoron I've included a foreach and you should see the results of the SQL query and the LINQ query are the same.